# Als - verb position

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm reading Harry Potter and there's a sentence there that buffled me.

"Schließlich taten sie für gewöhnlich so, als **hätte** sie keine Schwester"

Shouldn't it be
"Schließlich taten sie für gewöhnlich so, als sie keine Schwester **hätte**" ?

I thought *als* sends verbs to the end (a subordinating conjuction) not only when talking about past events, but also when using it like "as if".

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Something is wrong on that sentence: "Schließlich taten sie für gewöhnlich so, als hätte sie keine Schwester"  Either it is "hätten", because taten is plural or it is "tat" for singluar and "sie" refers to a female.

Comment: I didn't quote the previous sentence, but I believe the first sie refers to the Mr and Mrs Dudley while the second sie refers only to Mrs Dudley.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So there is nothing wrong with the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

German native speaker here.

"As if" translates to "als ob", and indeed, you could use that to create the sentence "als ob sie keine Schwester hätte".
The same could be achieved with "wie wenn".

With just "als" though, that always requires a main clause with the conjunctive verb form.

See this site for some examples: https://mein-deutschbuch.de/irreale-vergleichssaetze.html

Comment: "Als" is indeed a bit tricky, because it can mean "as if" or "when", with a different word order.

Comment: @RHa AFAIK _als_ would be _as_, not _as if_, while _als ob_ or _als wenn_ would be _as if_

Comment: @Marzipanherz But in sentences like "Schließlich taten sie für gewöhnlich so, als hätte sie keine Schwester" the *ob* can be omitted if the verb follows.

Comment: @RHa True. Now I get the point you wanted to make.

Comment: If `als` alone in this case is the start of an main clause, then shouldn't the verb theoretically be in the second position `Schließlich taten sie für gewöhnlich so, als sie hätte keine Schwester`. ?

Comment: Or is it a special form of a main clause where the verb comes first, which implies a suggestion (for example `Stelle man sich eine Welt ohne Eier vor.`) as described here: (https://resources.german.lsa.umich.edu/grammatik/verb-first/#imperativ ?